# Is it possible to set the background color of an image (HTML email) when displayed in Outlook?

Tags: html, css, email, outlook, html-email

I have a service that emails customers to update them about certain events. The service builds the emails and sends them to clients after these events occur. 
The templates render perfectly well on Thunderbird, Gmail and other email clients; but they don't work on outlook. Here's a portion of the markup concerned:

```
public static final String ROW = "<tr>"
            + "<td align=\"center\" width=\"30%\">"
            + "<img bgcolor=WARNING_COLOR style=\"background-color:WARNING_COLOR; border-radius: 20em;\" alt=\"Warning_Icon\" src=\"WARNING_ICON\" height=\"40\"  width=\"40\"></td>"
            + "<td rowspan=\"2\" >TYPE</td>"
            + "<td rowspan=\"2\" width=\"30%\">ERROR_MESSAGE</td>"
            + "<td rowspan=\"2\">NAME</td>"
            + "<td rowspan=\"2\">DESCRIPTION</td>"
            + "</tr><tr><td align=\"center\" width=\"30%\">ID</td><tr/>";
```

Words with all capitals are replaced before sending the content. The issue arises with the `bgcolor` and `background-color` elements. I set them to orange or red. In Outlook the colours don't work, the images work, but they are white on a white background. I've tried setting with the name (`orange` and `red`) and the six digit hex codes (`#FFA500` and `#FF0000`) with no success. 
I've tried including/excluding `bgcolor` but it doesn't work.

Is it possible to get this to work in Outlook? 
At this point I'm tempted to just render multiple `png` files, one for each status and type and be done with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way would be to use a transparent background PNG or GIF image and set the background color on the TD (preferrably using the 'bgcolor' HTML attribute as not all recognize the CSS).

so essentially it would become:

```
public static final String ROW = "<tr>"
            + "<td bgcolor=WARNING_COLOR align=\"center\" width=\"30%\" style=\"background-color:WARNING_COLOR; border-radius: 20em;\">"
            + "<img alt=\"Warning_Icon\" src=\"WARNING_ICON\" height=\"40\"  width=\"40\"></td>"
            + "<td rowspan=\"2\" >TYPE</td>"
            + "<td rowspan=\"2\" width=\"30%\">ERROR_MESSAGE</td>"
            + "<td rowspan=\"2\">NAME</td>"
            + "<td rowspan=\"2\">DESCRIPTION</td>"
            + "</tr><tr><td align=\"center\" width=\"30%\">ID</td><tr/>";
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that out.

Comment: OK, that works, but it looks terrible. I think it's safe to say the answer is no! thanks for your help.